# Deciphering "easy" ciphers without hints

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cipher-selection, decryption

I've been keen on IT Security for a long time now and I've learned a lot about networking & security. However trying a "decryption challenge" I'm lacking what I think is basic encryption/decryption knowledge.

So I've got a ciphertext without knowing about the algorithm or key used encrypting the plaintext. I assume that this cipher is not "too hard" (no AES e.g.) to crack, because it would be an overkill for a simple challenge.

I want to mention that I would like to crack it on my own, but I need advice in which direction I should go - what's most likely to be used, how I can verify if some encryption algorithm is used or not, etc.

About the cipher:
The Cipher contains [a-zA-Z0123456+] without whitespaces, while some patterns are recurring (same characters are repeating in the same order a few times in the cipher).

What I've already done:

- I tried a frequency analysis to see if it's just substituted monoalphabetically sign for sign - without success (many results staying at ~8%, no one above 10%)
- I had a look at classic transpositioning and substitution methods which lead me to encryptions like Vigenére, Autokey, Beaufort and so on. However, those are designed to work with non-numeric alphabets as far as my understanding goes.
- I calculated the "Index of Coincidence" being about 0.06, which should tell me that problably a substitution is used (I haven't yet figured out completely how this works in detail)
- I already tried to separate the cipher at points where suspicious, recurring "words" are, just to find something that seems like separator-signs. However it's not much clearer afterwards and I'm not sure how to go on.

What I need would be a good advice on decrypting such ciphers as I'm currently running out of ideas what to try.

I hope somebody can help me out here as I'm really interested in the topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And it's not base64 encoding?

Comment: Try base64 decoding.
Command: base64 -d [cipher/file]

Comment: @RoraΖ Didn't think of that before, but no - there's nothing readable after decoding from Base64. Any other ideas I might have missed to check?

Comment: The unreadable code is most likely the actual cipher text/binary data.  Using base64 is just a means of making it easy to copy and paste for users of the challenge.

Comment: Ah.. alright, that's what you meant. Well.. honestly I don't know how to handle the result yet (looks more unrelated than before, just many special characters mixed up with periods and numbers here and there). Sorry for the strange description.

Comment: you could try https://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/ - python script that attempts to identify the hash type.

Comment: It's not found (info: I noticed the script is pre python3, but you can correct it easily as raw_input() is renamed to input() and print now needs parenthesis). 
I'm also quite sure the ciphertext isn't hashed as I'm supposed to read what the result is. Cracking a 1000+ characters cipher won't be the "challenge".

Comment: I just came across the Community "Cryptography" - I think this question would fit better in there. I'll just have to figure out how to move it.

Comment: @UsuallyNot We can do that for you.  If you could post the challenge site it might help us see it for ourselves, and then we'd be able to point you in the right direction from there.  You can also hop in [the DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) to talk things out.

Comment: @RoraΖ I appreciate your effort, but I don't quite get what you want to do for me - as I'm sure the cipher isn't a hash, trying cracking it like it would be one won't help. I'm sorry, but I prefer not to show the challenge as it's specifically a challenge intended for me afaik (not a mass-challenge).
I've discussed this topic with a friend of mine who mentioned that seeing more and more recurring characters in the same order could most likely point to Vigenère.
I'm looking forward to hop into a Chatroom, but I'll inform you in case I do.

Comment: Crossposted on [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29860/deciphering-easy-ciphers-without-hints) (with a remark that it is a cross post).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cross-posted to Crypto